# Date conversation error during jaxb marshall on a JPA object using eclipselink

Tags: jpa, jaxb, eclipselink

I stuck on this Date conversation error for quite some time ... 
I am using eclipselinks, openJPA under TomcatEE environment, and trying to use jaxb doing marshalling. I met a problem for marshall one JPA object, which contains Date, TimeStamp elements. 
The exception message is ---

javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [3/19/12 12:00 AM], of class [class org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[createTs-->createTs/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.entities.ApplicationEntity --> [])], could not be converted to [class java.util.Date].]

The strange thing is jaxb converting works OK for some customers, but not some other customer. I tried to put @XmlElement(type=Date.class) for this field crtTs, It doesn't work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

LL

Comment: OpenJPA appears to returning its own subclass of Date, that EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) is not expecting.  Could you update your question to include the full stacktrace?

Comment: Blaise, It is YOU! Thank you! Thank you!!

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the issue you are seeing and have entered a bug (http://bugs.eclipse.org/383639).  I have also added an answer that gives a workaround that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.  You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/383639

---

**WORK AROUND**

**DateAdapter**

You could use an `XmlAdapter` to convert the problematic date into a proper `java.util.Date`.

```
package forum11145711;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Date, Date>{

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public Date marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        if(null == date) {
            return date;
        }
        return new Date(date.getTime());
    }

}
```

**Root**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to leverage the `XmlAdapter`:

```
package forum11145711;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Date date;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

**MyDate**

Below is the subclass of `java.util.Date` I'm using in this example.

```
package forum11145711;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyDate extends Date {

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code you can use to prove that everything works:

```
package forum11145711;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setDate(new MyDate());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <date>2012-06-27T10:39:49.081</date>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, Thank you SOOOO much for helping this case. Yes, the above workaround works!! I will keep an eye on the bugfix. Best Regards!